# How can I select all tables with a certain amount of foreign keys in them?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How can I select all tables from a database which have for example one foreign key in it? Can I as well get all tables in my database in ascending order in regard of the number of foreign key?
Thanks!

I did found out how to get the foreign keys for one certain table. But how can I iterate such a query over all tables?

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "<database_name>" 
      AND TABLE_NAME = "<table_name>" 
      AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

Is it further possible to select by count of foreign keys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this query on for your target database. Please make sure the query returning correct data by some manual checking before rely on it :)

```
SELECT [Table Name],COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
    SELECT fk_tab.name as [Table Name],
    fk.name [FK_Name]
    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN sys.tables fk_tab
    ON fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
)A
GROUP BY [Table Name]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

For MySQL, Can your please try this. I simply copied it from [Here](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/mysql/list-foreign-keys)

```
select concat(fks.constraint_schema, '.', fks.table_name) as foreign_table,
       '->' as rel,
       concat(fks.unique_constraint_schema, '.', fks.referenced_table_name)
              as primary_table,
       fks.constraint_name,
       group_concat(kcu.column_name
            order by position_in_unique_constraint separator ', ') 
             as fk_columns
from information_schema.referential_constraints fks
join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
     on fks.constraint_schema = kcu.table_schema
     and fks.table_name = kcu.table_name
     and fks.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
group by fks.constraint_schema,
         fks.table_name,
         fks.unique_constraint_schema,
         fks.referenced_table_name,
         fks.constraint_name
order by fks.constraint_schema,
         fks.table_name;
```

Comment: I tried to get it work. I changed it to:
    SELECT [Table Name],COUNT(*)
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT fk_tab.name as [Table Name],
        fk.name as [FK_Name]
        FROM sys.foreign_keys as fk
        INNER JOIN sys.tables as fk_tab
        ON fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
     )
    GROUP BY [Table Name]
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
But I still got a syntax-error

Comment: I tired it but I can not get it to process the query

Comment: @Momo I have added the query for MySQL. Please check.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. Do you know how I can groupt that output by the amount of foreign key relationships?

Comment: Thanks it is working fine. How can I order by the amount of foreign keys?

Comment: For MSSQL, Its already added in the query - ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a simple aggregation query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "<database_name>" AND
      REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

However, this is counting the number of columns with declared foreign key relationships.  It is not counting the number of foreign keys, because two columns can be used for a single foreign key relationships.

It is not clear what you are really trying to do, so perhaps this query does do what you want.

Comment: thanks for the advise. Fortunately I only have single foreign keys. I did not think of the possibility that a table have multiple columns as one foreign key.

Comment: There was an **AND** missing between the two **WHERE**-statements. But I still got an error that the **<database_name>.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE** table does not exist.

Comment: It works now! Thanks! Is it possible to list those entities which have 0 foreignkeys in their table as well?

Comment: You basically need to select all tables that are not in this list . . . you can use `not in`, `left join`/`where`, `not in`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that is it what I am looking for. How can I get this done?
    `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*)
    FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "iteraskill" AND
          REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
    );`
I thought it should look something like this, but I still get errors.

Comment: Use `not in` rather than `not exists` with that construct.